Question on finding intervals of monotonicity via first derivatives
Regarding the treatise on Monotonicity via Derivatives in Thomas Calculus (section 4.3), please see the following corollary and its proof below.
Corollary - Suppose that ƒ is continuous on [a, b] and differentiable on (a, b).  If $f'(x) > 0$ at each point $x \in (a,b)$, then f is increasing on $[a,b]$
Proof - Let $x1$ and $x2$ be 2 arbitrary points in $[a, b]$ with $x1 \lt x2$. The Mean Value Theorem applied to $ƒ$ on $[x1, x2]$ says that -
$$
f(x2) - f(x1) = f'(c)(x2-x1)
$$
for some $c$ in $(x1, x2)$.
Now, both terms on RHS of the above equation are positive, therefore $f(x2) - f(x1) > 0$. This concludes the proof.
To find the intervals where a function ƒ is increasing or decreasing, we first find all of the critical points of ƒ. If $a < b$ are two critical points for ƒ, and if the derivative ƒ' is continuous but never zero on the interval (a, b), then by the Intermediate Value Theorem applied to ƒ', the derivative must be everywhere positive on (a, b), or everywhere negative there.
Now, here is my question. In the last paragraph when describing on finding the intervals where the function is increasing or decreasing, the author assumes that the derivative function is also continuous. However, what happens when the derivative is discontinuous in (a,b)?
For example, I was thinking of the below derivative function.
Sample derivative function
This is an example of the derivative function with $a=-2$ and $b=2$. And $f'(0) = 1$. So the derivative is defined at all points. However, the derivative is positive and negative both, so the function is increasing as well as decreasing afterwards between the 2 critical points. Am I correct in thinking that a function is not always monotonic between 2 critical points, and the book doesn't tell all details?

Have a look at Darboux' theorem. The derivative of a function always has the intermediate value property, even if it is not continuous.

Thank you @AnCar. I was not aware of this theorem. This answers my question.
